# R: Is there a clean way to obtain a single Data Frame of samples obtained in a loop?

Tags: r, subset

I have a huge dataset containing observations about 1000 different entities. Each entity has an ID between 1 and 1000 and there are no missing IDs. Since the dataset has more than 1 million rows, I want to obtain a subset with 10 random observations for each entity to make some analysis.

The following code does the trick, but it looks cumbersome and its performance is poor.

```
library(dplyr) # sample_n is a dplyr function
samples <- sample_n(dataset[dataset$Entity == 1, ], 10)
for (x in 2:1000) {
  samples <- rbind(samples, sample_n(dataset[dataset$Entity == x, ], 10))
}
```

Could you please share some ideas for doing the same in a better fashion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to use a for loop when you already use `dplyr`. The `group_by` command exists to do all the work you do with your for loop in a more efficient way.

A simple example will be this:

```
library(dplyr)

dt = data.frame(mtcars)

dt %>% group_by(cyl) %>% sample_n(3)
```

To sample 3 rows for each `cyl` value.

So, consider that `cyl` here is your `ID`. Something like

```
your_dataset %>% group_by(ID) %>% sample_n(10)
```

will do the job.

Comment: Thanks @AntoniosK, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @AntoniosKs answer why not consider using `data.table` now that you have a large dataset. If your data is stored as a data table in `DT` and you want to sample 10 observations for each `ID` then

```
library(data.table)

DT[, .SD[sample(.N,10)], by = ID]
```

should give you a substantial speedup.